# How to correct an error when I use PHP in a script HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I saw in another post in stackoverflow that it was possible to include PHP code in  HTML tag but I have this error: "Undefined index: select_years" when I use this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   console.log(<?php echo $_POST["select_years"];?>);
</script>
```

Comment: have you posted that variable? usually you would have an if around to check if that variable exists

Comment: you shouldn't ever mix PHP and JS - they're executed different and could lead to unexpected behaviour

Comment: which value you are getting in $_POST["select_years"]?

Comment: Once you fix the undefined index, you'll probably want to do `console.log(<?php echo json_encode($_POST["select_years"]);?>);` for safety.

Comment: What makes you think that this error is in any way related to Javascript? Why not check for array indices before using them, in the same way you would do it in pure PHP?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <?php
 $select_years="";
 if(isset($_POST["select_years"])){
    $select_years=$_POST["select_years"];
 }
 ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 console.log("<?php echo $select_years;?>"); //Added Double Quotes
 </script>
```

Try This, works for sure

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

For post, get or request methods before printing or using them check if the request is submitted or not.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["select_years"])){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   console.log(<?php echo $_POST["select_years"];?>);
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain further where your code checks whether a request was submitted or not?